# Create outlook appointment from cell data

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

firstly I am a novice so please let me know if you dont understand or I have the incorrect terminology.

I am attempting to create a VBA macro where by when a date is entered within a certain cell range it automatically creates an appointment in Outlook starting on the date entered as an all day event and where data such as appointment title and subject are drawn from other cells in the same worksheet.

For example. Say I format column C as date cells, id like the macro to run when a date is entered in any cell within the C column that creates an appointment with the title taken from B2 & A1 and sets an appointment reminder to two days before.

Ive attached a screen shot which I hope explains the above a little better

Perhaps explaining the reason why I want to create such a macro might help too. I am an Urban Planner that works within Government and when I receive a planning application to assess I have 28 calendar days from the lodgement date to request any further information from the applicant. So I wanted to create a macro that would automatically create an appointment in Outlook for that date to remind myself. I do have other macros id like to create that are similar but baby steps haha.

I did attempt this myself, by basically finding two different tutorials. One for the cell data change and another to have outlook create an appointment. Now since I am a novice, of course I couldnt get it to work. But here was my attempt at combining the two

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C5")) Is Nothing Then

Sub CreateAppointment()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olAp As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set olAp = ol.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With olAp
    .Subject = "Board Meeting - 2020 annual results"
    .Location = "Meeting Room 007"
    .Start = "06/01/2020 05:30 PM"
    .End = "06/01/2020 06:30 PM"
    .RequiredAttendees = "a@b.com, c@d.com"
    .OptionalAttendees = "d@e.com"
    .Body = "Important decisions, Annual profits/losses"
    .Send
End With
    
End Sub
```

If you would like any further info id be happy to provide.

[image]

Comment: "*couldnt get it to work*" Please be more specific. What happened when you ran your macro?  Also, given your scenario, did you consider creating a Task instead of an Appointment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare one function inside another. So, move the `CreateAppointment` sub outside of the Excel's event handler and declare it separately:

```
Sub CreateAppointment(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim ol As Outlook.Application
  Dim olAp As Outlook.AppointmentItem

  Set ol = New Outlook.Application
  Set olAp = ol.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

  With olAp
    .Subject = "Board Meeting - 2020 annual results"
    .Location = "Meeting Room 007"
    .Start = "06/01/2020 05:30 PM"
    .End = "06/01/2020 06:30 PM"
    .RequiredAttendees = "a@b.com, c@d.com"
    .OptionalAttendees = "d@e.com"
    .Body = "Important decisions, Annual profits/losses"
    .Send
  End With
End Sub
```

Don't forget to add a COM reference to Outlook in the VBA editor so you could get access to the object model (type library). Also I've added a parameter which you could propagate from the Excel's event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C5")) Is Nothing Then
   CreateAppointment(Target)
  End If
End Sub
```

And the last bit you need to set properties of the new appointment item based on the Excel's `Range` instance passed to the sub.